# Validate string that contains template in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem trying to validate this string...

So, the user selects a template: `q(     )`. Then, the user fills in the contents inside the brackets which can end up like this:

> q(a,b,c)

I have tried different ways using regex to validate this String, but it keeps returning the answer "No". I believe the problem is `"q("` and `")"` in my regex as I am not sure how it should look like.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
String data2 = "q(a,b,c)";
String regex2 = "q([a-zA-Z0-9,'])"; 

if(data2.matches(regex2)){
    System.out.println("yes");
}
    else{
        System.out.println("No");
}
```

I do have an alternative way by removing "q(" and ")" in data2 string, but I rather have it in regex without the need of removing characters in a String.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Parentheses have special meaning in regexes...

Comment: Yeah I realised that when I was working on regesx on a different string. Just don't know how I should declare "q(" and ")" in regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses (and escape the escape character so that it compiles) and add a `+` at the end to indicate one or more characters

```
String regex2 = "q\\([a-zA-Z0-9,']+\\)";
```

You can read the meaning of every character in a regular expression in the `Pattern` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: I pulled the trigger too fast and missed. You win.

Comment: @Floris On stackoverflow, everyone is a winner.

Comment: Ahh so it was "\\". Didn't realise it was possible to apply "\\" after letters. I did have a very similar solution to yours, but didn't think of "q\\(" part.